# I cannot delete a record "Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails. How do I fix this?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I tried to delete a record in ratings table,then

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`fyprojectdb`.`ratings`, CONSTRAINT `FKdyash6f91887unaan9mj9b460` FOREIGN KEY (`answer_id`) REFERENCES `answers` (`answer_id`))

this error occured. How to fix this error. I have mapped both entities correctly.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ratings")
public class Ratings {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long rating_id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = false, length = 45)
    private Short ratingValue;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "answer_id")
    private Answer answer;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    private Question question;
//getters and setters
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "answers")
public class Answer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long answer_id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = false, length = 100)
    private String fullAnswer;

    /*Many to one mapping question*/
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    private Question question;

    /* Many to One mapping with users*/
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;
//getters and setters
```

Comment: You try to delete parent row while child row(s) exists. You must either delete child rows previously or set ON DELETE SET NULL option for this FOREIGN KEY.

Comment: The error states you cannot update or add a row; it mentions nothing about delete. Turn on SQL logging and show the code you are using to try to delete Ratings; I suspect you have something else in the transaction, as there should be no issue deleting an instance (or instances) of Ratings; this constraint should only prevent you from adding/inserting a Ratings that points at an Answer that does not exist. Check that you aren't removing a ratings (and its graph) and then somehow causing the same ratings instance to be merged/persisted back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` here

```java
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "userId")
private User user;
```

It means that the `User` has to be deleted after deleting any of `Ratings`.

Better to use `RatingEntity` for the entity and `RATINGS` for the table name.

**General rule**

Never use any `cascade` with `@ManyToOne` part of the association!

Also always use `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` with `@ManyToOne`.

```java
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "answer_id")
    private Answer answer;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    private Question question;
```

Comment: Ratings has a Foreign key to user, and the mapping setup described means the opposite:  Ratings has a Foreign key to user, so Ratings must be deleted before you delete User. Cascade operations have their place, and certainly can and should be used on ManyToOne relationships. Not all and not always, but certainly not a blanket 'never'. Lazy should have no effect on this issue either; use of lazy should be usecase driven, not arbitrarily always done.